# Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly

Tags: visual-studio-2019, blazor

I have installed Visual studio 2019  in windows 7 pc.when I run Blazor Web Assembly from Visual studio 2019 then its shows an error message as "Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages".

Please advise how to resolve this issues

Comment: VS has 'workloads', make sure you have ASP.NET Core. And the latest VS.  There is a separate Installer app.

Comment: Windows 7 went end of support (aka. life) on 14 January 2020. [Polite question] Why are you trying to develop modern apps on a deceased operating system?